# If $\int _{ 0 }^{ 1 }{ f(x) dx } \leq10$ then is it correct to say $\int _{ 0 }^{ 1 }{ {f(x) }^2dx } \leq100$?

Tags: integration

If $\int _{ 0 }^{ 1 }{ f(x) dx } \leq10$ then is it correct to say $\int _{ 0 }^{ 1 }{ {f(x)}^2 dx } \leq100$ ?

If not,why?Do provide counter examples if you can.Thanks.

Comment: Sorry.Corrected the typo.

Comment: Did you try any example at all before asking?

Comment: Note that an integral designating lower and upper "limit" is signed; then you can easily come up with an example.

Comment: @Did Yes like f(x)=$10*{\pi/2}cos(\pi/2)x$

Comment: @SanchayanDutta Why not try the simpler $f(x)=-11$ first?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen i simply forgot about checking the negative sign.Really foolish of me.Phew!

Comment: Even if one would assume that $f>0$ it would not be true, so it is not only about the sign. One can take $f(x)=1/\sqrt{x}$. Then, $\int_0^11/\sqrt{x}\,dx=2$ while $\int_0^1 1/x\,dx$ diverges.

Comment: Exercise: Find every nonnegative function $f$ such that $\int_0^1f=10$ and $\int_0^1f^2\leqslant100$. (There are not many...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One may observe that, for example,
$$
\int _0^1-10(1+x)\:dx=-15<10
$$ whereas
$$
\int _0^1100(1+x)^2\:dx=\frac{700}3=233.33\cdots>100
$$

Comment: Aha!So that was all about the negative sign..:-P!! It was so foolish of me!

Comment: "So that was all about the negative sign" **No**.

Answer (score 5):

For a non-negative counterexample, consider $f(x)=100, 0 \leq x \leq 0.1$, $0$ otherwise.

Then 
$$\int_0^{1} f(x)\,dx=10$$
but
$$\int_0^{1} f(x)^2\,dx=1000$$

Answer (score 2):

No, for example take $\int_0^1-100dx=-100\leq 10$ but $\int_0^1(-100)^2=10000>100.$